# Javascript Closure in a loop when declaring new var

Tags: javascript, closures

My question might look similar to this question: [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example?rq=1)
But the difference is that I declare a new local var in each iteration:

```
var funcs = []; 

for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  var b = i; 
  funcs[i] = function() {console.log("My value: " + b);}; 

}

for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
  funcs[j](); 
}
```

So by declaring a new variable and pass it to the closure context, I expected the value of b in each function is different but my output is:

```
My value: 2
My value: 2
My value: 2
```

It always has the value of the last `var b` in the iterations. Can you help me to understand this?

Thank you.

Comment: You can't declare a variable local to the block scope with `var`, since var-declared variables are always hoisted. Use `let` instead (ES6 only).

Comment: [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let)

Comment: Regardless of where a `var` declaration appears, it's always treated exactly as if it had appeared at the beginning of the enclosing function (or `<script>` body if not in a function). Thus the fact that you put your `var` declaration inside the `for` loop makes no difference. The new ES2015 `let` statement is a different story.

Comment: If you read all of the answers in the question you reference, you'll see this talked about too, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/29558498/1615483

Comment: @PaulS. Why did you mark it as duplicate? It seems totally different situation. Look at the first answer, it will make you more clear. I think, this answer is the correct answer for this question, where this will not mean anything in the question you referenced.

Comment: @PaulS The answer you just referenced is provided on  
"Apr 10" and `let` in Javascript is introduced in ECMAScript 2015 (6th Edition, ECMA-262). So, that answer has already been invalid / incorrect now, where he says, "JavaScript does not have block scope. Variables introduced with a block are scoped to the containing function or script".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable *b* is not defined in each iteration. Your code is not any different from this:

```
var funcs = [];
var b; 

for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    b = i; 
    //... etc
}
```

Your intended behaviour is reached with the `let` keyword (ES6). As explained on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let):

> `let` allows you to declare variables that are limited in scope to the block, statement, or expression on which it is used. This is unlike the `var` keyword, which defines a variable globally, or locally to an entire function regardless of block scope.

Alternatively, you could define b as a function argument, and then fix it with `bind`.

```
var funcs = []; 

var f = function(b) {console.log("My value: " + b);}; 

for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    funcs[i] = f.bind(null, i);
}
```

Or, you could define a closure to get the local scope you needed:

```
var funcs = []; 

for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    funcs[i] = (function () {
        var b = i; // now b is local: to this anonymous function
        return function() {console.log("My value: " + b);}; 
    })();
}
```

And, a small, but better, variant of the above passes *i* as an argument to the closure, so also there *b* is local to that closure:

```
var funcs = []; 

for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    funcs[i] = (function (b) {
        return function() {console.log("My value: " + b);}; 
    })(i);
}
```

Then even better, define the function (factory) once:

```
var funcs = []; 

var f = function(b) {
    return function() {console.log("My value: " + b);}; 
})(i);

for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    funcs[i] = f(i);
}
```

But, you will agree the `let` syntax is so much more readable.